# How to change data source of deployement in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins to automate build and deployment of a java web application. Currently I am able to automate build and deployment of the application in tomcat using jenkins. But, I also need to change the datasource.properties file of the application in order to point to a specific schema. Is there any plugin to do that?